# Remote Deploy to WebSphere 8.5 using maven

Tags: maven, websphere, websphere-8, maven-cargo, wsadmin

I would like to control a remote deployment of a maven generated EAR over to an existing WAS instance not running on the build server.

Ideally, I would like to do this within Maven so that I can remote deploy in say the integration-test phase then proceed to run some JMeters in the verify phase. I guess this is pretty standard.

I have looked around and am unable to find a sensible way to do this in WAS 8.5.

There are a few posts:

[Remote Deployment to WAS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118559/remote-deployment-to-websphere-6-1-x-using-wsadmin)

[websphere7am-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871962/how-to-do-websphere-7-deployment-automation-using-maven)

[Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/WebSphere+8.5.x)

and others around the web, including IBM. None seem to offer a way to achieve a remote deploy to WAS 8.5

Does anybody have a solution?

EDIT 1: 
Further confirmation from IBM that no official maven solution exists can be found here:

[WAS 8.5 - Using Ant to automate tasks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=04fe3969-dd7c-43c8-b0f0-d6aa8266c5d4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no Maven plugin for full-fledged WAS 8.5, only for WAS Liberty Profile. But that one does not support deployment to remote server.

Remote deployment can be done using [WsAdmin Ant Task](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/InstallApplication.html) & [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)

Comment: From further research it does appear that the Ant route is the only route available today. Further google searches turned up these posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117785/using-ant-to-deploy-ear-to-remote-websphere-application-server

I guess my big hope is that either websphere7am-maven-plugin or Cargo manage to work this out. I did read on the IBM website that the ANT scripts are the only way today. C'mon IBM maven has been around for a while now...

Comment: You might want to file a feature request via link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe&BRAND_ID=181&PROD_FAM_ID=262&PROD_ID=544&COMP_ID=17&OS_ID=16&PRI_ID=3&PRESELECT_DROPDOWNS=true
At least Liberty Profile team is quite responsive.

Comment: I have added a link to IBM forum confirming this to the original question

Answer (score 4):

You will soon be able to automatically deploy to WebSphere remotely using Jenkins. You can create a maven project and have Jenkins automatically deploy to WebSphere with the plugin listed below. If you're interested, follow it since I'll be taking feature requests for a limited time.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebSphere+Deployer+Plugin

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.orctom.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>was-maven-plugin</artifactId>e
    <version>1.0.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wasHome>${env.WAS_HOME}</wasHome>
                <applicationName>${project.build.finalName}</applicationName>
                <host>${local or remote address}</host>
                <server>server01</server>
                <node>node01</node>
                <virtualHost>default_host</virtualHost>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

From https://github.com/orctom/was-maven-plugin

**Updated on 5/29/2014**

Developer of this plugin states on github, "*`1.0.1` and `1.0.2` is not working, please don't use them!*", so I've updated this answer to show version `1.0.3`.

**Updated on 1/27/2015**

Updated to '1.0.8'.

Comment: From the author: `NOTE: WebSphere Application Server installation required on host box! But no need to be configured, nor running.`

Comment: According to @Pool comment, that's why it is not *remote* deploy.

Answer (score 3):

we're using [was6-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/was6-maven-plugin/) to perform both local and remote deployments to WAS 7. Internally this plugin uses ant tasks from wsadmin so I guess it would also work with WAS 8.5.

Comment: Could you please add more information? I inherited old project where was obviously used WAS7+maven(was6-maven-plugin). I am able to use it for local deployement, but not for remote. Thanks